# cassandra.bat -f -- issue to start cassandra in windows 8.1 pro

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm setting up cassandra in windows 8.1 pro. i have tried with JDK 8, Open JDK 12, and JDK 12. what i am missing to install cassandra in windows.

```
C:\apache\apache-cassandra-3.11.4\bin>cassandra.bat

Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
```

I expect CASSANDRA should start.

Comment: `WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.` Yet another reason never to run Cassandra on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue by pointing JAVA_HOME to jre1.8.0_212/ instead of jdk1.8.0_212/. i am trying to understand why it work only with JRE 1.8 why it is not working advanced JDK (JDK12). 
can anyone analyzed ?

Comment: Cassandra does not support a JRE beyond 1.8 until Cassandra 4.0 is released.  As I'm sure you know, many things have been deprecated/added/changed between Java versions 8 and 12.   Getting the underlying code to run on Java 11 required a major effort: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608